# showing boxes after executing my C file handling program in visual studio

Tags: c

i write a code for writing and reading the file after giving input to it it shows some boxes instead of text as output . please help me to solve this problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    FILE* fp;
    char c;
    printf("DATA INPUT\n");
    fp = fopen("Input.txt", "w");
    while ((c = getchar() != EOF)) {
        putc(c, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("INPUT", "r");
    while ((c = getc(fp)!=EOF))
    {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

and here is the output screenshot
[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw9Ny.jpg)

Comment: You mean `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` (wrong brace)

Comment: Alway, always, but really always with no exception under no circumstances you must check if `fopen` succeeds. What do you think happens if a file you try to open does not exist?

Comment: there are no syntax errors and runtime errors in my code but the problem is , at output it is showing some boxes instead of text that what i ve given as input to the file. u can understand by seeing the screenshot of output

Comment: @chaitanyaji do what i suggested in the two first comments and your program will work as expected. Having a program that compiles properly without runtime errors is not a guarantee that the program works correctly.

Comment: And BTW: you write to `Input.txt` but you read from `INPUT`. Is that on purpose? How do you know the file `INPUT` exists?

Comment: if file is not there then it will create a file

Comment: Ah, no it won't. That's not what `"r"` does - it will return error if the file does not already exist. Please follow the advice and check the return value of `fopen`. Are you really saying you are intentionally writing to one file, `input.txt`, but then reading from another, `INPUT`?

Comment: Note that `getchar` reads from `stdin` but you want te read from `fp`. So use `getc(fp)`

Answer (score 0):

The priority is to comparison operator '!=' rather than affectation operator '=' that's why you need to add braces in your while statements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    FILE* fp;
    char c;
    printf("DATA INPUT\n");
    fp = fopen("Input.txt", "w");
    while (((c = getchar()) != EOF)) {
        putc(c, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("Input.txt", "r");
    while (((c = getc(fp)) !=EOF))
    {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Without braces it will compare getc(fp) with EOF which give 1 or 0 then store it in C.

Comment: the while statement will not break until you type EOF in your keyboard which can be done by holding alt and press 2 then 5 then 5 (it works only with numpad).

Answer (score 0):

You make a number of mistakes that are all mentioned in the comments. You program should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    FILE* fp;
    int c;                                       // EOF is an int
    printf("DATA INPUT\n");
    if (!(fp = fopen("Input.txt", "w"))) return; // file not found
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {             // put braces at the right
        putc(c, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    if (!(fp = fopen("Input.txt", "r"))) return; // file not found; use correct filename
    while ((c = getc(fp))!=EOF)                  // put braces at the right place
    {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    printf("\n");                                // make sure output is flushed
    fclose(fp);
}
```